# Caching for a standalone Java application

Tags: java, caching

I have gone through so many caching schemes like JCS, Redis,guava, memcache, ehcache, infinispan, hazlecast. I don't need any additional installation for my application and after process shutdown I want to persist data to disk and on process restart I want to retrieve that data back (it's not about the memory overflow data will be persisted to disk). I read the solutions and JCS, memcache, guava don't have such mechanisms.

Ehcache is having a mechanism to retrieve the persistent data back from disk after process retart but that's a enterprise edition. (Infinispan and hazleCast are almost same so I will prefer EHcache as it has a big support community).

Any suggestions which met the above conditions (retrieve the data back from disk after process restart) for a standalone Java application?